Не работают Google Maps API
Подскажите пожалуйста, закинул проект на GitHub, закомитил, запушил, задеплоил. Карты просто не отображаются. Локально все работает, открывают на GitHub-е, не работают. Ключ правильный доступ до него не закрывал, что не так не пойму.
Выдает эту ошибку только когда открываю проект на GitHub локально все чисто

Вот прописаный скрипт для отображения
<script>
  function initMap() {
  let mapReastaurant;
  let mapMerried;

  mapReastaurant = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector("#map-restaurant"),
    {
      center: {
        lat: 47.86636644473956,
        lng: 35.05962885142143,
      },
      zoom: 17,
    });

  mapMerried = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector("#map-merried"), {
    center: {
      lat: 47.83079492829225,
      lng: 35.15930220709443,
    },
    zoom: 17,
  });
}
</script>` 


Ошибку выдает только на GitHub, локально все чисто

Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?=> https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/264178 // по вопросу : 1. Убедитесь, что ваш API ключ позволяет запросы с GitHub Pages. Возможно, настраивается политика CORS, которая блокирует запросы. 2. Убедитесь, что ваш API ключ настроен для работы с реферерами (например, *.github.io)

может тут что найдете https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583891/google-maps-api-and-github-pages

А как проверить мой API на запросы и настройку с реферерами для GitHub?

https://console.cloud.google.com => Найдите ваш проект и откройте API ключ => Application restrictions HTTP referrers (web sites)=>В поле "Website restrictions" (Ограничения веб-сайтов) Добавьте в список допустимых рефереров ваш GitHub Pages домен => *.github.io

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374869/google-maps-api-key-url-restrictions

google maps js api has been loaded directly without loading=async => ошибка говорит о том, что скрипт Google Maps API не был загружен асинхронно //uncaught (in promise) invalidvalueerror => Это может быть связано с неправильными координатами //third-party cookie will be blocked => Это не должно напрямую влиять на отображение карт

попробуйте ваш скрипт изменить <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>   => добавив async и defer

прежде чем настройку реферов делать, попробуйте добавив два параметра, чтоб скрипт асинхронно загрузился

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview?hl=ru#Loading_the_Maps_API по ссылке из вашей ошибки есть примеры
